# Why isn't uploaded file saving in directory

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm having users upload `.xls`, `.xlsx`, and `.csv` files to my website. From there I want to save them to the folder `/upload/` in the same directory as the handler. I also want the name to remain constant. I have developed a code from what I have seen across the internet. Upon submission, the page turns white and no file is uploaded to the folder.

Form:

```
<form name="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="update_handler.php" method="post" >

    <b>Accepted File Extensions: .csv .xls </b><br>
    Please save your excel table as one of the <br>accepted file extensions prior to uploading.
    <br><br>
    <u>Upload File:</u> <input type="file" name="file"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Handler:

```
<?php

    $uploadDir = '/upload/';

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);

?>
```

Comment: Simple: You named your form `file` where it should be for your input `<input type="file" name="file">`

Comment: *face palm* thanks a  lot haha.. been a long weekend

Comment: You can delete your question, or I can make an answer to close it.

Comment: That was the first part of the problem, but I also made the error that @David corrected in his answer. I'll up both. Thanks you guys, very useful! EDIT: David deleted his post, so I will edit my OP to show you what was said that fixed my issue.

Comment: I was going to suggest that actually, about the use of `/upload/` as opposed to `upload/` if running your script from the root, but failed to mention it earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your form `file` `<form name="file"`

Where it should be for your input `<input type="file" name="file">` <= which am sure read something else, since it was edited. Both `form` and the input hold the same named attribute. Remove the one for the form or give it another name if it is required for something else.

Also, David pointed out another issue which I did think of earlier, but failed to mention after. Since I took your comment about the *"face palm"* had fixed everything. I would've commented, but did not.

I was going to suggest that actually, about your use of `/upload/` instead of `upload/` if running your script from the root, but failed to mention it earlier.

David seems to have deleted his answer.

Plus; you may need to use  `../upload/` or something similar, depending on the script's execution location and make sure proper write permissions are set.